# Judge two infinite series finite or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Here are two very simple infinite series represented as

$$S:= \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{k !}{N^k}\sum_{i\ge k}\frac{N^i}{i !}$$
$$\delta:= \sup_{k >0}\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} \frac{i !}{N^i}\sum_{i\ge k}\frac{N^i}{i !}$$where $N$ is a fixed positive integer.

Do you know how to judge the finiteness of the above series? It has some correlation with ergodicity in stochastic processes.Thanks!

Comment: Your second series seems a little odd.

Comment: For the first one, notice that  
\begin{align}
S =&\,  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum^\infty_{i=k}\frac{k!}{N^k}\frac{N^i}{i!}\\
=&\, \frac{0!}{N^0} \left(1+\frac{N^1}{1!}+\frac{N^2}{2!}+\cdots\right) \\
+&\frac{1!}{N^1}\left(\frac{N^1}{1!}+\frac{N^2}{2!}+\frac{N^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)\\
+&\frac{2!}{N^2}\left(\frac{N^2}{2!}+\frac{N^3}{3!}+\frac{N^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)\\
\vdots\\
+&\frac{k!}{N^k}\left(\frac{N^k}{k!}+\frac{N^3}{3!}+\frac{N^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)\\
\vdots
\end{align}
Notice the first term in each row is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first sum, it is enough to note that the coefficients $$a_{k}=\frac{k!}{N^{k}}\sum_{i\geq k} \frac{N^{i}}{i!} $$ are strictly greater than one. That is $a_{k}>1$. So, the sum tends towards infinity.

For the second one, regarding its finiteness, note that the series $$\sum_{i\geq k} \frac{N^{i}}{i!}$$ is the truncation error for the exponential function. By known theorems there is an explicit expression for this error. Namely $$\sum_{i\geq k} \frac{N^{i}}{i!} = e^{x_{0}} \frac{N^{k}}{k!}<e^{N}\frac{N^{k}}{k!},$$ for $x_{0}$ a real number between zero and $N$. Next, observe that $$\frac{N^{k}}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{i!}{N^{i}}=\sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{N^{m}}{m!} \cdot \frac{m!(k-m)!}{k!}<\sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{N^{m}}{m!}<e^{N}-1,$$ where the first equality is deduced by multiplying out the sum and rearranging, while the first inequality is due to the binomial coefficient being an integer. So, your supremum should be bounded by $$\delta \leq e^{N}(e^{N}-1).$$

I hope this is helpful!